# Can you use an Alfine 8-speed "disc" hub with a non-disc wheel?

Tags: brakes, drivetrain, internally-geared-hub

I have a city bike with a Nexus 8-speed and I'd like to rebuild the rear wheel with an Alfine 8-speed. The only hubs I can find all seem to be disc mount hubs. My city bike has v-brakes. Is it ok to use the "disc mount" hub on a non-disc wheel? The description seems to say "disc brake compatible", which sort of implies it's possible but not required to use the mount, but I would like to make sure before purchasing the hub.

Comment: My 11-speed Alfine came with a rubber boot to cover the disc mount if not used. There's no such thing as a "non-disc" rim, there are disc-specific rims, and v-brake compatible rims, but you can put a disc hub on any rim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the wheel is built with the appropriate rim (i.e., a rim with a braking surface) you should be fine. The hub simply has the mounts for a disc brake, one does not have to be mounted.